# Why aren't my images resizing? (Responsive Design)

Tags: css, responsive-design

So up near the top in the CSS reset, I added an additional rule to set all image elements to be max-width: 100%. However, my images aren't resizing properly, especially the gallery. It's supposed to stay in a horizontal bar, however I can't for the life of me get it to work, and I have no idea why. I'm not familiar with responsive design in particular. I bought a book and still don't understand it. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

http://lrroberts0122.github.com/DWS/lab5/index.html

http://lrroberts0122.github.com/DWS/lab5/css/main.css

Comment: As an additional note, the images are supposed to get smaller in order to stay in that horizontal space. Shouldn't something like max-width or width: 80% work? It's not, but that's what I thought was wrong and it's not doing anything. Instead, it just gets smaller and has a lot of excess space on the right.

Comment: I don't see anything in your CSS which is setting a max-width on img's - are you sure it's uploaded correctly?

Comment: I've been going back and forth editing and re-editing my files, so I left it blank for you guys. I added just img: width: 100%; and it kind of works, but the gallery at the bottom is still broken and that's mainly what I don't know how to fix. The last image in the mini-gallery instantly jumps to the bottom of the page instead of resizing fluidly like I'd want it to. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anywhere where you have specified what width the images should be. By adding `img { width: 100%; }` to your CSS it works for me.

Also you know you have included your CSS twice

Comment: The CSS at the bottom is my media queries for the break points if that's what you're talking about?

Comment: No i mean in your .html page you have `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">` twice, which is pointless. But you still haven't specified a width for `img` anywhere

Comment: It's there because of the media queries. Unless I can add the attribute multiple times which I'm not sure I can.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand you. Add `img { width: 100%; }` to make the image work, remove the first `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">`, it is redundant